# How to set a pre-defined path as inital path in argparse filebrowser type?

Tags: python, parsing, tkinter, argparse, file-type

With the below command I can create a file browser and view the files. But how can I give a default directory path to open every time in the below command? I am looking for an equivilant command as initial dir in Tkinter.

```
parser.add_argument('Openfile', type=argparse.FileType('r'))
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: `FileType` is a just a convenience feature.  If it doesn't suit your needs, don't use it.  Accept the argument as a plain string, and do your own file open, with added `dir` information as needed.  It can be argued that opening your own file with the `with` context is better anyways.

Comment: Iam new to the environment. Do you have an example to show how it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "default" parameter to initialize an argument.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#default

Use the "metavar" parameter to add an e.g. value to the help text.

Comment: I have tried to use default. Eventhough there is no error while defining a needed path in default parameter, its not working as expected. Do you have any other workaround?